# How to take one touch screenshot on Macbook Pro with Touchbar?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Whenever I touch the screenshot button on the touchbar, it asks sets the "Window" option by default and at a minimum I have to click the mouse to take the screenshot or tap on "Window" again.

How do I tweak the settings such that tapping the Camera button simply takes the screenshot without prompting for any other actions?

Comment: On my iMac running High Sierra, I can use the key combo: Command-shift-3 and this will take a screen shot of entire screen

Comment: Yeah, I know about that combo, but I just need a one click/touch screenshot really